# Set row spacing in UICollectionView when not using numberOfSectionsInCollectionView

Tags: uicollectionview, ios8.1

I would like to display cells 3 per row/section. My content is coming from API. If I do static like the code below, the cell spacing(and row spacing) are fine.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.5;
}
```

Since my data is coming from API, I set the itemSize width to display 3 per row and commented out the `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView`. However, the spacing per row has huge gap.

```
//-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
//    return 10;
//}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _results.count;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.5;
}
```

Is there a way to fix it? Or is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If someone might encounter same issue, this is how I fixed it.

Set this for your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
    [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
    [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:1.5];
```

And I you can delete this one:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1.5;
}
```